# Is this ring an integral domain? Prove or give a counterexample

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, integral-domain

I need to either prove this is an integral domain or give a counterexample.  I have yet to find a counterexample, but can't seem to prove it on my own.  Would love any advice/help! Thank you!
[image: Integral domain ring]

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Use the fact that $x^2-1=(x-1)(x+1)$.